# Flutter : Could not add card in apple pay

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, applepay

I have integrated apple pay into my flutter app using a plugin [flutter_pay: ^1.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pay),

I had followed the below steps:-

- Added tester in the sandbox with United states region and enable apple pay.
- Change region and date and time in iPhone to United states.
- Created merchant id in the Apple developer console.
- Enabled apple pay from Xcode.

Now I am going to add test cards into My Wallet (of my device) but I'm unable to add them and getting errors as below:

See attached screenshots.

[image: could not add card]
[image: Invalid card]

Using card details:-

```
FPAN: 3499 561538 91398
Expiration Date: 12/2022
CID: 1111

FPAN: 6011 0009 9458 9319
Expiration Date: 11/2022
CID: 111
```

Also tried out other cards [from test card details](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/).

Can anyone help me out to add the card?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Not yet, If you find any let me know.